# Jquery toggle slide up / down

Tags: jquery

I've got this code:

```
$('.nav li.mega').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var currentnav=$(this).closest('div').find('.subnav-container');
    if(!currentnav.is(':visible')){
        currentnav.slideDown();
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.toggleClass('is-active').children('ul').toggleClass('is-visible');
    } else {
        currentnav.slideUp();
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.toggleClass('is-active').children('ul').toggleClass('is-visible');
    }
});
```

This code should slide the sub navigation up and down. If the sub navigation is slided down and I click on another main nav point with a sub navigation, the slided down div should stay, the old sub nav should fade out and the new one in.

But I can't figure it out.

**Here my example**: http://jsfiddle.net/rzf7w69u/50

Thanks